# jQuery ajax returning wrong error code in IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am working on an application that uses a token-based authentication system, and it needs to work in IE9+. I am using jQuery 1.9.1 on this project.

So far, I have been developing in Chrome, and just got around to testing the app in IE9.

On each ajax call, I have an error callback that will redirect to the login screen if the server responds with a 401 status code. Code below:

```
return $.ajax({
    url: service_url+'/'+item,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("X-Token", $.cookie('access_token'));
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
            var redirect_location = encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname+window.location.hash);
            window.location = 'Login/index.html?e=Unauthorized&redirect='+redirect_location;
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine in Chrome, but I noticed in IE9 there was no redirect occuring. In the network tab of developer tools, I am clearly seeing a 401 error on the call:

[image: IE Network Tab Screenshot]

If I perform a `console.log(jqXHR.status)` or just `console.log(status)` in the error callback, Chrome returns `401`. IE9 returns `500` instead. I also tried checking the `error` parameter as well, which just returns the text `"error"` in IE9, but in Chrome returns `"Unauthorized"`. I don't want to always redirect to login on ANY error (I am handling server errors with messages in the page), only if the call returns unauthorized to force the user to login.

Any idea why this would be occurring, and is there a good workaround?

Comment: `status` is giving you 500 too, right?

Comment: Yeah `status` is also returning 500

Comment: does jqXHR.responseText give you what you expect?

Comment: In Chrome, it does, returning: `{ "Message": "Request is missing authorization token."}`. In IE9, it just returns an empty string.